# I can only add one order info my database

Tags: php, mysqli

On my e-commerce page when I click buy now in the form for the second time it doesnt add data to my data base... only the first time. Why is that?
I will paste in my action.php and form from cart.php

Here’s part of my action.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'order'){
    $miasto       = $_POST['miasto'];
    $kod_pocztowy = $_POST['kod_pocztowy'];
    $adres        = $_POST['adres'];
    $pmode        = $_POST['pmode'];
    $products     = $_POST['products'];
    $grand_total  = $_POST['grand_total'];
    $email        = $_POST['email'];
    $name         = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname     = $_POST['lastname'];
    $shmode       = $_POST['shmode'];

    $data = '';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (miasto,kod_pocztowy,adres,platnosc,produkty,ilosc_placona,email,name,lastname,dostawa)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss",$miasto,$kod_pocztowy,$adres,$pmode,$products,$grand_total,$email,$name,$lastname,$shmode);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data .= '<div class="text-center">
                <h1 class="display-4 mt-2 text-danger">Dziękujemy</h1>
                <h2 class="text-success">Twoje zamówienie zostało przyjęte!</h2>
                <h4 class="bg-danger text-light rounded p-2">Zakupione produkty : '.$products.'</h4>
                <h4>Twoje imię : '.$name.'</h4>
                <h4>Your e-mail : '.$email.'</h4>
                <h4>Your phone : '.$phone.'</h4>
                <h4>Łączna kwota zapłacona : '.number_format($grand_total,2).'</h4>
                <h4>Metoda płatności: '.$pmode.'</h4>
                </div>'
    echo $data;
}
?>
```

My form:

mvaxrzia22 martajarczynska2003@gmail.com
19:35 (0 minut temu)

do mnie

```
<form action="" method="post" id="placeOrder">
  <input type="hidden" name="products" value="<?= $allItems; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="grand_total" value="<?= $grand_total; ?>">
  <div class="row g-3">

    <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="firstName" class="form-label">Imię</label>
      <input style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jan" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Imię jest wymagane.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-sm-6">
      <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Nazwisko</label>
      <input style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kowalski" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Nazwisko jest wymagane.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="color: #fff;" class="col-sm-10">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">E-mail</label>
      <input style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="jankowalski@kowalskki.com" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        E-mail jest wymagany.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label style="color: #fff;" for="miasto" class="form-label">Miasto</label>
      <input style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="miasto" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Poznań" required>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Miasto jest wymagane</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label style="color: #fff;" for="kod_pocztowy" class="form-label">Kod pocztowy</label>
      <input style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="kod_pocztowy" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="42-800" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Poprawny kod pocztowy jest wymagany</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label style="color: #fff;" for="adres" class="form-label">Adres</label>
      <input style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="adres" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Kowalskiej 31" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Poprawny adres jest wymagany</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr style="color: #fff;">

  <h4 style="color: #fff;" class="mb-3 text-center lead">Płatność</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="pmode" class="form-control">
      <option value="" selected disabled>-Wybierz metodę płatności-</option>
      <option value="PAYu Online">PAYu Online</option>
      <option value="dotpay">dotpay</option>
      <option value="cards">Karta debetowa/kredytowa</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <h4 style="color: #fff;" class="mt-5 mb-3 text-center lead">Dostawa</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select style="color: #fff; background-color: #111;" name="shmode" class="form-control">
      <option value="" selected disabled>-Wybierz metodę dostawy-</option>
      <option value="kurier">inPost Kurier</option>
      <option value="paczkomat">inPost Paczkomaty 24h</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input style="background-color: #F5E595;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Kupuj teraz" class="btn btn-block mt-3">
  </div>





  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated but, the `$phone` var seems to be undefined and you're missing a `;` at the end of the line before `echo $data;` http://prntscr.com/vsdgbi

Comment: Also, this bit is almost certainly a mistake `isset($_POST['action']) == 'order'` and should be `$_POST['action'] === 'order'`

Comment: Sadly it still Does not work, what else Can I try?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Here's a thorough [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/4205384) on debugging db related problems.

Comment: Please show your form

Comment: Also unrelated... I added the ; before echo $data and it still doesnt show Up

Comment: @WesleySmith oki i will paste it in the question

Comment: Someone plz Help

Comment: @WesleySmith now i deleted that data and now i cant add anything new even one Thingg... there must be some problem

Comment: I dont see any input with `name="action"` anywhere in your form.

Comment: @WesleySmith where should i put it

Comment: If you changed the code like we discussed above, your code is looking for `isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'order'` which means it expects there to be some input in the submitted form with `name="action"` whose value must be `order` when submitted to trigger your code. Either add some input with that value to the form, or remove that condition and instead check for some value that is in the form.

Comment: So i shouldp put

```
<input name=„action” value=„order”>??